# In n-type semiconductor, when are dopant atoms considered positive ions?

Tags: semiconductors

Consider a pure piece of silicon semiconductor. Let’s say we dope it with Phosphorus. The extra electron in the outer most shell of the phosporous is in its conduction band as it is not part of any bond.

**My question is regarding the status of the dopant phosporous atom. When is it considered an positive ion?** When it’s free electron goes into its conduction band or when an E field is applied and that electron moves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the silicon crystal, when the dopant is implanted (or diffused), it loses its electron 'immediately' -- the electron can drift around the crystal easily (with thermal energy).

At very low temperatures, there may not be enough thermal energy to ionize the dopant, and in that case, some fraction of the dopant atoms are not ionized.

When an E field is applied the free electrons can move with the field. Generally they are already 'buzzing' about randomly from thermal energy; the E-field just gives them some additional bias in that direction.

Comment: I see. So even in an n-type semiconductor, some dopant atoms will be ionised as soon as implantation occurs due to the thermal energy? And then when an E-Field is applied, I assume it just allows even more dopant atoms to be ionised. The net charge of the N-type material will still be 0.

Comment: No. When an e field is applied, the (already free) carriers now begin to drift in the field. Only when the e field becomes very strong do the (now very fast) carriers begin to ionize silicon atoms and generate more free carriers.

Comment: Ok. So the dopant atoms essentially lose their extra electron almost immediately after implantation and they become positive ions?

Comment: Yes. Implantation is very energetic (100's of kV energy) -- implanted dopants are implanted already ionized. After that, there is an annealing step to repair the damage in the crystal.